# What's the best way to "append" to a list of strings stored in a JSONB column in a table PostgreSQL such that duplicates are not stored

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Say there is a table `employee`

```sql
create table employee (
    emp_id varchar(100),
    tags jsonb NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]' :: jsonb;
);
```

One of the rows has the following information in the `tags` column

```
["TagA", "TagB", "TagC"]
```

Currently to update the column with additional values I perform the following query

```sql
UPDATE employees SET tags = employees.tags || to_jsonb('["TagD", "TagA"]'::jsonb) where emp_id = 'EMP-111'
```

However this adds duplicates to the cell and makes it look like

```
["TagA", "TagB", "TagC", "TagD", "TagA"]
```

which is less than desirable for my use case. Currently to circumvent this I've handled duplicates in post-processing at the application layer.

Is there an efficient way to remove duplicates like "TagA" at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_agg` with `distinct` in a subquery:

```
update employees set tags = coalesce((select jsonb_agg(distinct v.value #>> '{}') 
    from jsonb_array_elements(employees.tags || to_jsonb('["TagD", "TagA"]'::jsonb)) v), '[]'::jsonb) 
where emp_id = 'EMP-111'
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=2cb6cfa7a15b51f1f6745f7d2736a242).

Comment: How would it take care of null values? I tried out a test query where initially tags is assigned as '[]' and I run an update query of adding an empty list. Fiddle - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ab65b26c870022e2867475da2138cfa5

Comment: @mr1dul6 You can use the `coalesce` function to replace `null` results with an empty array: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=39d128f6f55cb241cce76c4847c10e13